# intermix vs mix

Tags: verbs, differences

What are the differences? Are they everywhere interchangeable? Isn't [intermix](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intermix?q=intermix) redundant, because if you mix A and B, then you must be mixing them *together*? For example, can **mix** be used in:

> Law and opinion are here so **intermixed** that it is difficult to say whether opinion has
>   done most to produce legislation or laws to create a state of legislative opinion.

Source: P14, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use *mixed together* there. *Intermixed* however is more formal than *mixed together*, so it's probably more appropriate here.

As a general rule, when you have a single word and a phrasal verb that carry the same meaning, the single word will be more formal, especially if it is from a French or Latin origin.